# Acessar os componentes dos filhos de um TObject

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Ohayou Developers, 
Gostaria de saber como faz para acessar os filhos de um objeto, Por exemplo.
Tenho um TRectangle e uma TLabel com seu filho. Eu precisaria acessar o TLabel para alterar, por exemplo, seu texto, cor etc.
Qual seria o comando para isso?, considere também que o filho pode ser outro tipo de objeto, por isso coloquei Tobject no titulo.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Quando se fala em "filho" do objeto, há duas interpretações possíveis:
1) O objeto é um TComponent e Owner de seus filhos, que podem ser acessados pela propriedade Components. Por exemplo:

```
for i := 0 to Form1.ComponentCount - 1 do
  if Form1.Components[i] is TLabel then
    TLabel(Form1.Components[i]).Caption := IntToStr(i);
```

2) O objeto é um TControl e Parent de seus filhos, que podem acessados pela propriedade Controls. Por exemplo:

```
for i := 0 to Panel1.ControlCount - 1 do
  if Panel1.Controls[i] is TLable then
    TLabel(Panel1.Controls[i]).Caption := IntToStr(i);
```

Geralmente o Form é o Owner de todos os componentes e os controles visuais que contém outros controles (quando se movimenta o pai os filhos vão junto) são os Parents de seus filhos.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa acessar o Pai do componente primeiramente acompanhado dos componentes dentro dele para ter acesso. Fiz um exemplo para ter acesso ao `TLabel`.

Espero que ajude.

```
var
  oLabel: TObject
begin
  oLabel := FindComponent('nome do TRectangle').FindComponent('nome do TLabel');
  if Assigned(oLabel) then
    TLabel(oLabel).TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.White;

end;
```

Esse exemplo funcionará se caso o `TLabel` se encontrar dentro do componente `TRectangle`, agora se por exemplo existir dentro de um `TRectagle` um componente `TToolBar` e então dentro do `TToolBar` existir o `TLabel`. Teria que somente acrescentar um FindComponent() buscando o `TToolBar`.

```
oLabel := FindComponent('nome do TRectangle').FindComponent('nome do TToolBar').FindComponent('nome do TLabel');
```

Comment: +1, e se você souber o nome do TRectangle, ou seja, se ele for um objeto visível no design, você pode pegar o atalho: `NomeRectangle.FindComponent('nome do TLabel');`

Comment: @JúniorMoreira bem lembrado

Comment: Não teria como fazer o acesso direto, sem ter que procurar? por exemplo
Trectangle.Children[0]."PegaComponente"(Tlabel).Color etc etc.